# Iteration index in a Julia for loop

Tags: loops, iteration, julia

I have to code a very simple `for` loop in Julia, which I reproduce below:

```
result=fill([],6,1)
E=rand(5,5)
D=3.27
k=2
for s in [0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,2]
    result[??]=exp.(-(E.^2/D)/(2*s*k))
end
```

At each iteration, I want that the `i`-th element of `result` is filled with the result of the function, which uses the `i`-th element of the array `[0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,2]`. So I don't know what to put inside of the brackets `[??]`. 
So far, I tried

```
for (index, value) in enumerate([0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,2])
       result["$index"]=exp.(-(E.^2/D)/(2* "$value" *k))
end
```

but it doesn't work. Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're currently initialising the results to be a one dimensional array, but they're actually two dimension. So you need to switch the results as follows

```
result = fill(Array{Float64}(undef,0,0),6,1)
```

You shouldn't need to do any conversion of the types and the following will just work.

```
for (index, value) in enumerate([0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,2])
  result[index]=exp.(-(E.^2/D)/(2*value*k))
end
```

Rather than initialising the results, you can just map across the values as well which becomes a bit easier to read.

```
result = map(x -> exp.(-(E.^2/D)/(2*x*k)), [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2])
```

---

Some comments on performance

```
using BenchmarkTools

function t1()
  result=fill(Array{Float64}(undef,0,0),6,1)
  E=rand(5,5)
  D=3.27
  k=2
  for (index, value) in enumerate([0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,2])
    result[index]=exp.(-(E.^2/D)/(2*value*k))
  end
end

function t2()
  E=rand(5,5)
  D=3.27
  k=2
  result = map(x -> exp.(-(E.^2/D)/(2*x*k)), [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2])
end

@btime t1() # 4.904 μs (49 allocations: 9.66 KiB)
@btime t2() # 4.812 μs (50 allocations: 9.64 KiB)
```

As you can see, no real difference in the performance. If you want to improve performance then it's easiest to try and pull the constants out of the inner loop.

```
function t3()
  E=rand(5,5)
  D=3.27
  k=2
  f = -(E.^2/D)/(2*k)
  result = map(x -> exp.(f/x),  [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2])
end

@btime t3() # 3.168 μs (31 allocations: 5.53 KiB)
```

Comment: Jesus, it was so simple... And thank you for the tip concerning the initialisation of the array ;-)

Comment: I had the code written with your `map` version before, but I'm trying to rewrite my whole code so that Julia can run it faster. There are lots of discussions concerning `map` vs `for` and I'm comparing the two versions of my code, where all the `map` cases were replaced by `for` loops, so that I can keep the fastest solution.

Comment: I don't see significant performance differences between the two implementations. Running BenchmarkTools.@btime gives 4.9μs for each solution. A simple performance improvement would be to pull out some of the logic, from the loop. I'll edit the solution with some comments on it

Comment: Yes for this case , there is no difference :-) but for other cases in my code there are some differences

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `result` should be a vector of matrices:

```
els = [0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,2]
result=Vector{Matrix{Float64}}(undef, length(els))
E=rand(5,5)
D=3.27
k=2

for s in 1:length(els)
    result[s]=exp.(-(E.^2/D)/(2*s*k))
end
```